# Microsoft Graph FindMeetingTimes Gap

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Hopefully I'm not the only one having this issues. When I request meeting time suggestions, which includes an attendee and time constraints, I get a response of 5 meeting suggestions. The issues is, that the slots have a gap in time, some times several hours. However, all attendees have that gap time as free; additionally, if I change the duration or increment the time one direction or another, the missing time slots show up. On a related note, is there a way to request more than 5 meeting time suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I think the perceived "gap" here is because you're expecting the meeting suggestions to be returned in chronological order, which is not the case. The FindMeetingTimes API tries to infer the user's preferred meeting times based on their past meetings, and the meeting suggestions are returned sorted by what the API thinks would be the most preferred. It's most likely that the "missing" time slots are lower down in the ranking, and you're not seeing them because you are only getting the default 5 results back.

You can request more results by including the `maxCandidates` parameter in your request body. See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_findmeetingtimes#request-body for details.

Comment: Thanks, for the response. Now that I know how to adjust the number of returns, that'll help. However, that still doesn't solve the main problem. I attempted to retrieve suggestions for a 30min duration, and it returned 5 items, as expected, with no gaps in time. However, when I adjust the duration to 1hr, it returns no suggestions, even though the start time is the same as the previous request. Can you advise on that? Thank you

Comment: Did you get an emptySuggestionsReason property in the result?

Comment: I did not. Oddly, when I select, for example, 8am as the start time & 30min duration, it shows me suggestions broken into half hour increments up to 10 am. However, if I change the duration to 1hr, leaving the start time the same, it returns no available times.

Comment: Add the `returnSuggestionReasons` property in your request body set to `true`. Hopefully that will give you a bit more explanation in the response. Due to the heuristic nature of this API it's hard for me to give a definite answer. So much depends on the data and history in the mailbox you're using.

Comment: I've added that bool, and it returns AttendeeUnavailable, even though that time slot shows up under a different duration.

Comment: Can you update your post above with the request bodies you're using for the two requests?

Comment: Jason, thank you very much for all the assistance. The issue seems to have resolved itself, the time slots are coming in as expected for all durations. If it re-surfaces, I’ll update this question. Again, thank you.

Comment: I had a similar issue I set the time contraint start to sdt = new DateTime(sdt.Year, sdt.Month, sdt.Day, 0, 0, 0); I added a minute and all is good e.g..0, 1, 0