# meetingDuration in findmeeting times api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Microsoft Graph API 
**Findmeeting times api** 
what happens when meeting time is less than 30mins(like 10mins)?Because Findmeeting Times search only for every 30 mins. It does not search times in between. For example I want for 10 mins meeting with someone 8 to 10. It returns 8.00 t0 8.10 and 8.30 to 8.40.Why can't it return 8.10 t0 8.20 and 8.20 to 8.30 ?Here is the inputs and outputs

### Input

---

```
{
  "attendees": [
    {
      "type": "required",
      "emailAddress": {
        "address": "kumar.muthu@mic123.com",
        "name": "kumar muthu"
      },
    }
  ],
  "timeConstraint": {
    "activityDomain": "unrestricted",
    "timeslots": [
      {
        "start": {
          "dateTime": "2018-03-27T18:00:00",
          "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
        },
        "end": {
          "dateTime": "2018-03-27T18:30:00",
          "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "meetingDuration": "PT0H10M"
}
```

**Output**

---

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#microsoft.graph.meetingTimeSuggestionsResult",
    "emptySuggestionsReason": "",
    "meetingTimeSuggestions": [
        {
            "confidence": 100,
            "organizerAvailability": "free",
            "meetingTimeSlot": {
                "start": {
                    "dateTime": "2018-03-27T18:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
                },
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": "2018-03-27T18:10:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
                }
            },
            "attendeeAvailability": [
                {
                    "availability": "free",
                    "attendee": {
                        "type": "required",
                        "emailAddress": {
                            "address": "kumar.muthu@mic123.com"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "locations": [
                {
                    "displayName": "RM-CHN-Training-Room1",
                    "locationEmailAddress": "RM-Chennai.Trainning-Room1@mic123.com"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "DEV BAY",
                    "locationEmailAddress": ""
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "Conference room near Security",
                    "locationEmailAddress": ""
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "Any Phone Booth or WebEx",
                    "locationEmailAddress": ""
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "Austin",
                    "locationEmailAddress": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**why it doesn't send timings between 8.10 to 8.30**

Comment: also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49386142/how-to-use-findmeetingtimes-in-microsoft-graph-api-to-schedule-a-meeting

Comment: Maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111479/

Comment: Thanks @ Karlheinz.I read through the page you referenced here.Then according to that it includes AI right?.Correct me if I am wrong. Whether the suggestions are based only on organizer preferred meeting times or both organizer and attendee preferred meeting times

Comment: Sry, the algorithm that is used is not documented. 
So I can't give you any helpful information.
It could be that an AI or just an algorithm based on some statisitcs and calculated scores is used to propose meetings.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you why the limitation is there. It's not documented in the [Find meeting times API documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_findmeetingtimes). But Outlook, which presumably uses the same or a similar API, has the limitation in the UI as well:

[image: Outlook find meeting times error]

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your filter for 10minutes worked, now the results appear limited due to some default filters applied, try adding these params and play with the results.

```
"isOrganizerOptional": "true",
"returnSuggestionReasons": "true",
"minimumAttendeePercentage": "100"
```

Hope it helped.